# How to switch authentication providers seamlessly?

Tags: authentication, firebase-authentication, data-migration

I was planning on using firebase auth for authentication (I had already implemented my own strategy but thought it might be easier to use firebase for launch), in the event I ever want to change the authentication provider either to another 3rd party service such as auth0 or back to my own strategy, how could I move users over while keeping password information?

Currently, it seems impossible to do so as firebase doesn't provide me with any information on how the passwords are encrypted. What would be a professional way to handle this? (I've also considered only moving new users to the new authentication provider and writing an abstraction layer that interfaces with the different auth providers)

Answer (score 1):

Firebase provides multiple ways to get/export the users from your project with a documented encryption method.

See for example the [documentation for the Admin SDK on getting a list of users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users).

More information on the encryption can also be found in the [documentation for the `firebase` CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth), which has an `auth:export` command. This documentation includes a list of the fields exported.

To learn more about the actual hashing used, have a look at this open-source library: https://github.com/firebase/scrypt